# SQL Server database Mirroring on different servers

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, instance, mirroring

I tried to perform SQL Server database Mirroring(with SQL Server 2008R2). And I got success to perform mirroring with "High Safety" mode.

And for that I have used three instances of SQL Server database.One for Principal second for Mirror and third for Witness.

As I mentioned I used three instances but all of those instances was on the same SQL Server.

But when I tried to perform mirroring with different SQL Server instances then it was not successful.

So I want to know can we perform mirroring with different SQL Server instances? Or we can only do it with instances on same server?

Also in mirroring how many instance we can configure as a Mirroring server ?

And is it a right way to achieve database availability? Or is there any other/advance way to achieve database availability and security?

Comment: Mirroring is not designed for *Instance* availability on *one*machine.  It is intended for protecting databases across two machines (3 if a witness is used).  What errors are you seeing?

Answer (score 2):

> So I want to know can we perform mirroring with different SQL Server instances? Or we can only do it with instances on same server?

Yes of course you can do it. Perhaps it is best idea or a suggested good practice to keep Principal mirror and witness on different servers. Of course Principal and mirror would be different servers.Have a look at article [Prerequisites, Restrictions, and Recommendations for Database Mirroring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366349%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [Things to consider before database setting database mirroring](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2001270)

> Also in mirroring how many instance we can configure as a Mirroring server ?

Question is little incorrect or not properly formed. For one principal you can have only one mirror server. Its is not like Logshipping where you can have multiple standby servers for one primary server.

> And is it a right way to achieve database availability? Or is there any other/advance way to achieve database availability and security?

To answer this question to absolute correctness one would require to know your environment RPO and RTO. A simple SQL server cluster with mirroring can work good. You can even go storage replication, SRDF various technologies for Hardware redundancy. Database mirroring *almost* provides a high availability for SQL Server database. If you want OS redundancy as well create SQL Server cluster and then move databases to cluster and then create database mirroring for the desired database.

PS: In whole question you did not provided what error you got while configuring mirroring. Nonetheless if you read the articles I gave you would be able to configure it correctly

Comment: ,thanks for your reply.That is really helpful to understand the mirroring concept.
But will you please more elaborate where i can get the concept of mirroring on different servers,in the above links which are suggested by you ? Because i did not get it.

Comment: Pawan I guess you are beginner in mirroring I would advise you to start with Microsoft Mirroring doc. Its best written so far although for SS2005 but concepts are explained well http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc917680.aspx